# How to Use UrlFetch in Google App script for getting Inner fields of Facebook page feed?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, google-apps-script, urlfetch

I am trying to get the inner fields of facebook page feed json data through urlfetch function in Google App script but i am getting

> invalid argument

error. 
I saw some other resolution but non of them work in my case this is my codes 
I am trying to get the atttachment inner fields eg fields=attachments{subattachments,url} the braces are the problem here so how to parse this through urlfetchApp?

```
var url = 'https://graph.facebook.com'
+ '/pageneme/feed'
+'?fields=name,full_picture,message,attachments{subattachments,url}&access_token=MYACCESStoken'



var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {'muteHttpExceptions': true});

var json = response.getContentText();
var jsondata = JSON.parse(json);

var data =jsondata.data
var pagename =data[0].name
var images= data[0].full_picture
var messages =data[0].message
    var attachment = data[0].attachments 

var media =data[0].subattachments


Logger.log(images);  //check this and adjust following for loop and html 
showFeed function accordingly
 Logger.log(messages);
Logger.log(attachment);
```

Answer (score 2):

Got it by myself thanks for those down voted

I had unsafe characters in my url. I had to encode the url:

```
 var url = 'https://graph.facebook.com'
+ '/pagename/feed'
//   + '?access_token=' + encodeURIComponent(getToken());
+'?fields='+ 
encodeURIComponent("name,full_picture,message,attachments{subattachments,url}")

+'&access_token=token'
```